# Creating Azure Marketplace App

Tags: azure, azure-marketplace

Recently I have become interested in creating a Microsoft Azure Marketplace plugin for our API Developer Portal product [DynamicApis.com](https://www.DynamicApis.com).  We currently have a BizSpark account but I am having trouble finding out where to start when it comes to creating and uploading a Marketplace application on Azure.  Here are some questions that I have.

1. What is the process that I need to go through in order to apply to put my product on Azure Marketplace?
2. I am assuming there is an API that Azure has that you use to plug-in your application.  Where can I find information on that API, sandbox environment, etc?
3. Is there any helpful documentation, contacts, or any material that anyone can provide me to help with this process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get started with publishing in the Azure marketplace, follow this [getting started guide](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/marketplace-publishing-getting-started/).